# Como apagar somente 1 campo do formulário?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um formulário de entrada de código de barras de notas fiscais da empresa, que possui campos como motorista, carro usado na entrega e etc. Para que no momento da entrada, o usuário não precise preencher as informações para cada nota, eu uso:

```
body onload='window.history.back();'
```

Dessa forma, o formulário já aparece preenchido com as informações anteriores.

Acontece que o campo específico para o código de barras também retorna preenchido, fazendo com que os usuários precisem apagá-lo para ler o próximo código.

Alguém sabe como eu consigo recarregar a página somente com este campo do código de barras limpo? Sou iniciante em `PHP`, `javascript` e tal...

Edit:

Segue meu formulário:

```
<form action="verif_codigo.php" method="POST">

    <!-- Select Motoristas -->

    <select class="form-control" name="motorista">
        <option value="0">Selecione o motorista...</option>
        <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
        <option value="3">Opção 3</option>

    </select>

    <!-- Select Carros -->

    <select class="form-control" name="carro">
        <option value="0">Selecione o carro...</option>
        <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
        <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
        <option value="4">Opção 4</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Input Código de Barras -->

    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="codigo" name="codbarras" placeholder="Digite aqui o código de barras da NF-e..."/>


    <input class="form-control btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Gravar"/>
    <input class="form-control btn btn-warning btn-xs" type="reset" value="Limpar"/>

</form>
```

Tenho este form, quando o usuário clica em submit, os dados gravam no banco e o formulário recarrega usando o `body onload` que citei antes. Só que o form recarrega todo preenchido, e eu preciso que o campo `codbarras` recarregue em branco, para que o usuário só faça a leitura do próximo código sem precisar apagar o campo.

O melhor que consegui até o momento foi usar:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('codigo').value='';"
```

No `input` do campo `codbarras`, só que isso só apaga se clicar no campo...

Comment: Sua pergunta é interessante, porém ela está incompleta para obter uma resposta. Poste o formulario e o código em javascript que aplica as condiçoes a ele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa de script para conseguir o campo vazio. Adicione `autocomplete="off"` no `input` do código de barras que o campo vai estar sempre vazio quando voltar para a página:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text" id="codigo" name="codbarras" placeholder="Digite aqui o código de barras da NF-e..."/>
```

Mais informações sobre autocomplete você encontra **[neste link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)**.

Você pode inclusive adicionar o atributo, se for útil, **[autofocus](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)** no campo para que quando a página carregar o cursor já esteja no campo do código de barras pronto para receber a informação, sem ter que clicar nele:

```
<input autofocus autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="text" id="codigo" name="codbarras" placeholder="Digite aqui o código de barras da NF-e..."/>
```

Comment: dvd muito obrigado, cara! Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado a todos!!

Comment: @GuiFabri De nada. Dei uma atualizada na resposta, talvez melhore ainda mais a funcionalidade. Abs!

Comment: Velho, melhorou mesmo, agora retorna a página com o campo em branco e com foco, perfeito! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

você deixar no onLoad da seguinte maneira: 
body onload='window.history.back(); document.getElementById('codigo').value='' ';

Assim vc tera duas funções simultaneas durante o carregamento.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de fazer é chamando a função que você quer, no caso: **window.history.back();** dentro de uma função ao carregar a página e depois usando **Java Script**, zere o conteúdo do campo. Note que no exemplo abaixo o elemento com **id** = edt, está sendo iniciado no **HTML** com valor = *7891887261827*. 
Quando a página é carregada esse valor passa a ser apagado através da função **carregarFormulario()**.
PS.: Desculpe a falta de boas práticas deixando o JS junto com o HTML, mas é só para fins de demonstração.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function carregarFormulario() {
        window.history.back();
        var doc = document.getElementById("edt");
        doc.value = "";
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="carregarFormulario();">
<input id="edt" type= text value="7891887261827"/> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode colocar o atributo onLoad em seu campo do código de barras e atribuir a função para setar o valor nulo:

```
<input onLoad="document.getElementById('codigo').value='';" 
 class="form-control" type="text" id="codigo" 
 name="codbarras" 
 placeholder="Digite aqui o código de barras da NF-e..."/>
```